# Hide div when clicking outside the div or when clicking the descendant

Tags: jquery, hide

So I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it) and notice this answear

```
 $(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

However is it possible to make the descendant of the container hide the container when clicked on?

Comment: Yes, just remove the second clause in the `if` condition

Comment: Ah perfect thanks, just curious is it possble to do it with a click on the parent as well? @RoryMcCrossan